# Typescript is not transpiling Object.entries to ES5

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I noticed Typescript compiler doesn't transpile the `Object.entries` to ES5 when it generates the javascript files.

I don't want to import a polyfill, I was wondering what would be the best approach to replace those `Object.entries` into something that works for ES5?

Answer (score 2):

The `lib` key does not polyfill, it just "tricks" the compiler into believing said APIs are available so it won't complain during development. You're expected to use the pipeline outside of `TSC` to fix this, I'd suggest looking at Babel with Webpack.

Suggest looking at:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2017
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-runtime